# Change to checkbox list Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, checkbox, form-for

The code below will list `type` in a drop down list.

How do I change this drop down list into a checkbox list?

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name_cont %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
  <%= f.label :type, "Type"%>
  <%= f.select :type_id_eq, PartType.all.map{|x| [x.name, x.id]} %>
  <br/><br/>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @jvnill I don't know in details what is the reason of changing this, but I was asked by my friend to do the changes. so how change this?

Comment: I've done it with `simple_form` gem but I am not positive how to do it with `search_form_for`. Does `search_form_for` come with any gem?

Comment: @HélioSantos it comes with ransack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want to change the select to a list of checkboxes, you should expect an array in the controller.  This isn't part of your requirement so I'm just going to convert the dropdown.

```
<% PartType.all.each do |part_type| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'type_id_eq[]', part_type.id %>
  <label><%= part_type.name %></label>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just learned rails in 2 weeks time. Thank you very much, this is really helpful.

Comment: `<% PartType.all.each do |part_type| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'type_id_eq[]', part_type.id %>` I already changed with code you mentioned, it shows the checkboxes with list of part_type, but then when I click submit, this search button doesn't want to filter the result based on part which I click, do you know why?